# Add search text in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have list of array which I have to show when user type on input. I have used the jQuery autocomplete plugin which serves the purpose but I have to show search text as a new option in autocomplete list. For example

[image]

I have looked search and open method but i could not quite grasp it. Basically I want to add search text in source and then bind the drop down list again. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/275/)

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: aTags, 
    search:function(){
    },
    open:function(){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but within the `search` event method you could update the array with a new value, and [reset the `source` option, after the plugin has been initialized](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) (look at the bottom of the section).

```
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"],
    // store array length:
    len = aTags.length,
    // cache the element:
    tagsElem = $("#tags");

tagsElem.autocomplete({
    source : aTags,
    search : function( event, ui ) {
        // update array (replace/append value at the end of the array) :
        aTags[len] = tagsElem.val();
        // reset autocomplete source:
        tagsElem.autocomplete( "option", "source", aTags);
    },
    // EDIT:
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        // append "new" text to the last option:
        $('.ui-autocomplete li:last a').append(' <span style="color:red;">new</span>');
    }

});
```

<s>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gmbyaoy/)</s> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLx7uy7b/)

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for but just need to add new text in  beside search text

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want the array to be sorted alphabetically after appending the new value?

Comment: look at the screenshot which I have attached in my question.  The input value which you inserted in aTags array. I want to show it as a new value to user